# External .js file is loading & works but jQuery in it not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an external .js file that is loading and does work, but the jQuery in it doesn't work. When I paste the following code in my index.html file, it works:

```
<script>
  $( "div" ).css( "border", "9px solid red" );
</script>
```

All divs get a red 9x solid border. However, when I paste the exact same code into my .js file (minus the `<script>` tags), it doesn't work.

I know the external .js file is actually working because I've tested it with plain javaScript `alert("JS is working");`.

The jQuery library is called before the script file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
```

And if I check for jQuery by pasting the following code in the external file, I get "jQuery is loaded":

```
if (window.jQuery) {  
  alert("jQuery is loaded");  
} else {
  alert("jQuery is not loaded");  
}
```

Why isn't my jQuery working from the external file?

By the way, no error comes up in the console.

Comment: Are you working on a stand alone file? How do you load the HTML page?

Comment: @Allan, I'm not sure what you mean by how do I load the HTML page. I have an index.html, a bunch of css files, and one scripts.js. That's all I'm working with

Comment: Do you see any error message?try `$(document).ready(function(){/* do the work */})`

Comment: Are you working directly with a html file in the file system or are you working with a web server like apache, wamp or iis?

Comment: @LinYuan, $(document).ready() worked, thanks. I was confused because I learned js/jQuery through treehouse and they never used document ready. I realize now it's because they always called the script files at the bottom of the html, whereas I'm calling it in the head. Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use jquery in an external file you need to make sure DOM is ready. On stand alone page, just the jquery directly would work(like you said it does). However, when calling using an external js file you need to load the jquery code using below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "div" ).css( "border", "9px solid red" );
});
```

or

```
jQuery(function () { 
 $( "div" ).css( "border", "9px solid red" ); 
});
```

Comment: Yep, turns out I didn't realize I had to use document ready because I learned js by calling external files at the bottom of the body, whereas in this case I'm calling it in head. Thanks